Best Practice for Email Logging in CRM
My org is new to Salesforce CRM and we are building out the platform for UAT at the end of the year. The team developing this platform have gotten their Salesforce certified admin training and are certainly competent enough to get this ready for our Sales team.
One issue we are running in to is deciding how to log emails. We are unique in that our inside sales team does not cold call or reach out to customers in any way, they essentially develop client relationships and assist them in taking orders since out product’s configurations can be very complex. In that team’s ideal world, they would log every email between them and a client. In reality, Salesforce’s data and file storage costs are way too high ($10k+ for 10GB / year), we have dozens of Sales team members and thousands of clients, this would make data storage our highest line item in the companies budget outside of labor, it’s not an option.
I have tried implementing Einstein Activity Capture (EAC) in conjunction with Salesforce Outlook Integration and Sync (SOIaS). The main issue is that emails are not searchable, even after following this Salesforce documentation. Furthermore, altering associated objects (like Orders and Opportunities) using SOIaS is not allowed since EAC cannot interact with those object types in our environment.
I’m aware there are a litany of third party applications I can test to attempt to resolve this, but I’m more curious about best practice for our team’s workflow. When I search this problem online or try to troubleshoot with AI, the results interpret my issue as a marketing need and often suggest email campaign tools from the Salesforce App Exchange.
So what would you all recommend as far as how to approach this issue?
